# is the closure of a subalgebra also a subalgebra?

Tags: general-topology

Let X be a topological space and A a subalgebra of C(X,R) or C(X,C). Is the closure of A a subalgebra? Here C(X,R) and C(X,C) denote the set of all real continuous and bounded functions and the set of all complex continuous and bounded functions defined on X respectively.

Comment: If the topology on the function space (which you haven't explicited : are you using the compact open topology? EDIT : it seems you are using the Banach space structure on the bounded continuous funtions) is such that the natural operations of addition and multiplication are continuous, then yes, the closure of a subalgebra is a subalgebra.

Answer (score 1):

Yes in general, the closure of a subring $S$ of a topological ring $R$ is again a subring. The reason is simply $\overline{S} + \overline{S} \subseteq \overline{S + S}$ and likewise for $*$, by continuity of $+$ and $*$.