# If B is a subalgebra of A, conclude that B closure is a subalgebra of A

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, continuity, algebras

If B is a subalgebra of A, conclude that $\bar{B}$ is a subalgebra of A.

This is from Real Analysis by N. L Carothers chapter 12 exercise 3. The purpose of this is to lead up to the Stone Weierstrass theorem. I found this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630835/is-the-closure-of-a-subalgebra-also-a-subalgebra) but I cannot understand the answer.

The first part of this question requires us to show 
for f, g, h, k $\in$ A $\lvert\lvert{fg - hk}\lvert\vert$ $\leq$ $\lvert\lvert{f}\lvert\vert$$\lvert\lvert{g - k}\lvert\vert$ + $\lvert\lvert{k}\lvert\vert$$\lvert\lvert{f - h}\lvert\vert$. The second part required us to show that the multiplication operator is continuous.

Thanks again.

Comment: Do you not understand how to show these steps? Or do you not understand how they lead to an answer to your original question?

Comment: @MaoWao I have proved up to continuity of multiplication. However, I do not understand how this leads to the answer to my question. Thanks.

Comment: A map $\Phi$ is continuous if and only if $\Phi(\overline{E})\subset \overline{\Phi(E)}$ for all $E$. Now you can use the argument from the answer to the linked question to finish the proof.

Comment: @MaoWao By showing continuity of the multiplication operation we have ensured that $\bar{B}$ is closed under multiplication. Therefore, $\bar{B}$ satisfies the properties of an algebra coupled with the fact $\bar{B}$ $\subseteq$ A this now makes it a subalgebra of A.

Comment: One also has to show that $\bar B$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. But maybe you have done this before. Anyway, the argument is very similar.

Comment: @MaoWao yes thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$fg-hk=f(g-k)+(f-h)k$. Using triangle inequality and the fact that $\|xy\|\leq \|x\|y\|$ we get $\|fg-hk\| \leq \|f(g-k)\|+\|(f-h)k\| \leq \|f\| \|g-k\|+\|f-h\| \|k\|$. To prove that the multiplication map $(f,g) \to fg$ is continuous w ehave to show that $f_n \to f$ adn $g_n \to g$ together imply $f_ng_n \to fg$. For this note that $ \|f_ng_n-fg\| \leq \|f_n\| \|g_n-g\|+\|f_n-f\| \|g\|$. Also $\|f_n\| \leq \|f_n-f\| +\|f\|<1+\|f\|$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Now can you complete the argument?

Comment: Yes, this is what I got up to proving continuity of multiplication. However, I just do not see how continuity of multiplication coupled with your last inequality of ||$f_{n}$|| $\leq$ 1 + $||f_{n}||$ leads to $\bar{B}$ being a subset of A. I feel like I am missing something fundamental in my understanding. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @MatteoLepur The fact that $\overline {B}$ is a subset of $A$ requires no proof. By definition $\overline {B}$ is the closure of $B$ in $A$, so it is a subset of $A$.

Comment: Therefore, the purpose of proving continuity of multiplication is to ensure that the set $\bar{B}$ is closed under multiplication? Hence, we have that $\bar{B}$ satisfies all the properties of being an algebra making it an subalgebra of A, the ambient space?

Comment: @MatteoLepur You are right.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much!

Comment: To conclude the statement in a different way, you can also argue as follows starting from $|| f_ng_n - fg|| \leq ||f_n|| \cdot ||g_n - g|| + ||f_n - f|| \cdot ||g||$. We know that $||f_n - f|| \cdot ||g|| \to 0$ as $g$ is fixed. Furthermore, $||f_n|| \to ||f||$ (trivially) and thus $||f_n|| \leq C$ for all $n$. Hence, $||f_n|| \cdot ||g_n - g|| \leq C ||g_n - g|| \to 0$. So, $|| f_ng_n - fg|| \to 0$.